# How to increase the width of "float:left"-elements when an element goes down to next line?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I want to create a footer with 4 columns (sections). Each section has these styles:

```
.footer-sections {
  width:24%;
  min-width: 140px;
  float:left;
}
```

[image: grey=browser-window;black=footer;blue=sections]

As you can see, it is a responsive design I want to do. When the width of the browser window becomes small, the rightmost section will get down to the next line.
[image: when width decreases - 1]
[image: when width decreases - 2]

This is what will happen, but this is NOT what I want to accomplish.

My goal is to make the width of the sections as large as possible. What I want is:[image]

The problem is that I don't find any way to do this without using JavaScript. I want to accomplish this with only HTML and CSS.

I've tried the `width:auto`, but it doesn't work as desired.

I can't think of any way around.
Could you please lend me a helping hand on this? Any suggestions for solutions?

Answer (score 0):

If it's the 4th column that you always want to expand, you could do something like this:

**HTML**

```
<div class="footer-sections">
    <p>Column 1</p>
</div>
<div class="footer-sections">
    <p>Column 2</p>
</div>
<div class="footer-sections">
    <p>Column 3</p>
</div>
<div class="footer-sections">
    <p>Column 4</p>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
   .footer-sections {
    width:25%;
    float:left;
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
    .footer-sections {
        width: 33.33%;
    }
    .footer-sections:nth-child(4) {
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```

By using the pseudo-selector, nth-child, you choose the 4th child of `.footer-sections` class and make its width 100% when your resolution reaches 768px.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use .footer-section:last-child{width: 100%}

```
.footer-section:last-child{
     width: 100%
}
```